# Category in PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create a menu system and within that menu show whatever there is in MySQL based on one column!

#### Example

Currently, I can add products from my admin panel and it will be added into MySQL database. When I add a product, I can give this product a brand name i.e. diesel, levi, etc.

#### Question 1

Now I know how to show the contents of the database in MySQL in a PHP file by using `SELECT brand FROM products ...`, but this will show all the duplicated brands in my menu (e.g. 3 levi's, 6 diesels) and it will show them like:

> levi
>   levi
>   levi
>   Diesel
>   Diesel
>   Diesel
>   Diesel

But I only 1 need of each. How can I do that?

#### Question number 2

How can I link the diesel category only to products that have that brand? For instance, if someone clicks on the diesel category, php will only show products that have the diesel brand.

Comment: This is a question and answer site! anything can be asked as long as it is a question and can be answered in a way that is useful for other people to view and learn from. as far as I know my question is something that could help others if answered properly I know for fact this question will help many people to learn the the basics of PHP/MYSQL! as I mentioned in my question, I only needed the fundamentals of it and not a lesson on how to start with mysql and php. so if you cannot be bothered to answer the question then why do you even bother to comment on it?!?!?

Answer (score 5):

These are fairly simple relational database questions.

1; Use `DISTINCT` with your query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT `brand` FROM `products`;
```

2; You would need to use a `WHERE` clause, based on a parameter that you pass into `category.php` somehow. We can't really help you without existing code, but this should probably be what a file like `category.php` would be doing anyway.

That said, your brands should really be contained within a separate table and linked to from your products (probably one-many relation, one product can have one brand but a brand can have many products). You should really look up some database design concepts before continuing with your project, in my opinion.

---

Here's a very simple diagram of how your relationship would work:
[image: Simple relational]

Rather than querying `products` for your brands, you would simply `SELECT name FROM brand` to get a list of your brands.

Then, passing in your `brand_id` to `category.php`, you can get the products like so `SELECT * FROM product WHERE brand_id = 1`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know how to pass the id to a php page. but if i the products get saved in a different table and the brands get saved in another table, then How can show the products related to the brand selected in the menu? this is what I don't understand. there must be a very simple logic behind it but I dont get it!

Comment: @user2056633 I gave you the query right at the end

Comment: I am so confused its unreal! I don't even understand your simple diagram if i'm honest!

Comment: http://www.information-management.com/infodirect/20040312/8264-1.html

Comment: nope, still lost. Thanks anyway mate... will have to look on google for a simple way so I can understand it. cheers fella

Comment: The basic premise is that each separate entity would have it's own containing table. You could think of it as a way of not repeating data, if you had a 'brand' column on `product`, you would be repeating `Diesel` in every row. In my diagram, you would only have 1 `Diesel`, that is assigned to many products via it's ID. You could store anything off of that brand now, such as their website address, and present it however you want.

Comment: okay, I understand what you are telling me BUT and there is a big BUT with a BIG question mark next to it, lets say I have a separate table for brands. easy done! Now, how can I link a newly added product to a brand as they are in different/separate tables now!!!! this is the most confusing part for me!!!! Lets say the brands are in different table and I removed the brand column from the products table! Now I am going to add a new product from my admin panel, how can i tell the script that this new product's brand is X or Y?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25322/discussion-between-user2056633-and-rudi-visser)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a bit of SQL.

To get the different brands:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT brand from products'
```

To get the products for a specific brand

```
'SELECT products WHERE brand = "diesel"'
```

Be careful when writing the second query to ensure the user can't enter deliberately harmful data. Use prepared statements (PDO / mysqli), like:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT products WHERE brand = :brand');
$stmt->bindParam(':brand', $brand);
```

I'd echo the other answer and say you probably want to design your database a bit and work out what the data is and how it relates to other pieces of data.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:
Your query should be this:

```
Select distinct brand from products
```

Question 2 :

You should send the brand to category.php page:

For example the link should be like this:

category.php?brand=disel

Then on category.php page you should change your query somehow like this:

```
    if(isset($_GET['brand']))

        mysql_query("select * from products where brand='".$_GET['brand']."'");
    else
        mysql_query("select * from products");
```

and it is better to send your brand id instead of brand string to category.php for the query has better performance.